# elasticsearch type conversion

Tags: types, elasticsearch, mapping, grok

Not clear to me how do I upload data thru logstash to Elasticsearch with the proper 'type'

I mean, I have  a file with a syslog message including a part that is a DATE: I use GROK in logstash to parse the string identifying the %DATE and the other parts of the message,  then I send to output elasticsearch {}: the DATE in elsaticsearch appears as STRING and not as DATE. I would like this data to be properly qualifyed  with the right type in Elsaticsearch.
Same happens with other fileds, even if parsed by GROK as INT, DATE, etc thay all appears to be STRING in Elasticsearch 
How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Franco

Answer (score 0):

The typical thing to do with a date from your logfile is to replace @timestamp with that value.  First, use grok{} to make a field out of it, and then feed it to the date{} filter.

If you need to create a second date field in your event, you can specify a "target" in the date{} filter to put the result in a field of your choice.